# Need to sort String values while disregarding any positional changes to empty string values

Tags: java, string, sorting

I am trying to implement a scenario like this in Java.

I have an ArrayList

```
["23","5","","","54","20","","","","0"]`
```

At the moment, the list is not sorted, I want to sort it in a way that the positions of the empty strings `""` is maintained.

This means the empty strings are not sorted, other values are. 
**Example**
ArrayList

```
["0","5","","","20","23","","","","54"].
```

Notice that the position of the empty strings (initially at position 2,3 & 6,7,8 ) is retained afterwards and sorting is done with the non-empty values only. I am using Java,I will really like some ideas to start implementing this requirement. I have tried google but couldn't find a head start on this.

Please help,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like that: (Credits to **Tom** for his useful link)

```
    String[] arr = new String[] { "23","5","","","54","20","","","","0" }; // the original array
    boolean[] space = new boolean[arr.length]; // indicates whenever the index contains an empty space
    String[] target = new String[arr.length]; // the reslted array

    for (int i = 0; i < space.length; i++) // init spaces
    {
        space[i] = arr[i].isEmpty();
    }

    Arrays.sort(arr); // sort the original array

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].isEmpty()) continue; // just a space ignore that
        index = i; // real values start here
        break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < space.length; i++)
    {
        if (space[i] == true)
        {
            target[i] = ""; // restore space
        }
        else
        {
            target[i] = arr[index]; index++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a quite long code. Why haven't you tested it? Or, if you've tested it, why are the syntax errors in it?

Comment: thanks.. copy-paste errors. i can make it shorter but rather keep it clean and understanable

Comment: "copy-paste errors"? Copied from where? This still cannot run. If you don't have a Java environment installed, then try this: http://ideone.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will want to use something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class StringSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] numbers = new String[] {"23","5","","","54","20","","","","0"};
        // Save the indices to be able to put the sorted numbers back in the array
        LinkedList<Integer> indices = new LinkedList<>();
        // Keep an ordered list of parsed numbers
        TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
        // Skip empty entries, add non-empty to the ordered set and the indices list
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i].equals(""))
                continue;
            set.add(Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]));
            indices.add(i);
        }

        // Put the ordered integers back into the array
        for (int i : set) {
            numbers[indices.pop()] = Integer.toString(i);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }
}
```

It runs in O(nlogn) time because of the sorting, but that's doable.